# Django in VS2015

Tags: django, python-3.x, visual-studio-2005

I am completely a new comer to the python world. Basically I'm used to in Visual Studio.

I've installed VS2015 preview recently. It has new project template for python Django. I'm trying to explore it.

While taking a new project, I've got the following prompt-

[image]

What should I do regarding the **Location of the virtual environment**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the better concepts with Python is Virtual Environments. This allows you to run multiple versions of Python on the same server without them affecting each other.

I am no expert, but the general consensus I have seen is to have the env inside your project file. This keeps everything together and there is no confusion as to which environment is for what project.

If you want to read up about Virtual Env: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/